# Which current platforms can play Star Wars Monopoly?

Tags: star-wars-monopoly

When I was little I could play *Star Wars Monopoly* on a [CD-ROM](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uHurjhMvkjU) computer game. I'm not sure what computer system it was on, possibly Windows 98/2000 or something. **Is there any way to play *Star Wars Monopoly* on any of the devices/platforms I own now?**

My devices/platforms are:

- XBOX 360
- Windows 10 (Acer PC)
- Mac-Mini
- iPhone 4S

Comment: Usually people tend to dislike questions that are only answereable with lists. Neverthless, here's what is likely what you're looking for (at least for the PC version):  http://www.amazon.com/Monopoly-Star-Wars-PC/dp/1888208600

Comment: @Oak do we know if a CD-ROM that says "windows 95" on it would work on windows 10?

Comment: There's always Compatibility Mode

Comment: @Oak you could post that as an answer. :) If you want to. I don't know a lot about Compatibility Mode but I'll look into it.

Comment: I don't know if there are any more versions, so I can't do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution is to pick up the CD-ROM version and play it on Windows 10.  I loaded the game up on my Windows 10 box with no issues.  There was a one-time prompt to install DirectPlay, which took a few minutes, but after that it was Star Wars Monopoly time.